# Get video from medialibrary IOS

Tags: ios, delphi, video, media-player, firemonkey

I have this code to get video from medialibrary but i can't play it.

```
var
  Service: IFMXVideoManagerService;

begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXVideoManagerService,
    IInterface(Service)) then
  begin
    Service.GetVideoFromLibrary;
  end;
```

Help me to get the name of the file or advise the method for playing videos from media library in Delphi FMX IOS

Update:

I found this sample but only got image even you select video from medialibrary. Or may be i wrong?

```
var
  ImageService: IFMXTakenImageService;
  Params: TParamsPhotoQuery;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXTakenImageService,
    IInterface(ImageService)) then
  begin
    Params.RequiredResolution := TSize.Create(640, 640);
    Params.OnDidFinishTaking := DoDidFinish;
    ImageService.TakeImageFromLibrary(ScanfromImage, Params);
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.DoDidFinish(Image: TBitmap);
begin

end;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That code won't work, since IFMXVideoManagerService is not actually implemented anywhere. Where exactly are the videos you want to play?

Comment: Where is possible in my app. For example in mediaplayer but mediaplayer need filename.

Comment: Your example in your updated answer is for selecting an image from the collections of media on the device; not a video. In order to select a video, you'd probably need to use the Photos framework. It's too complex an answer to provide a complete solution here. There's some example Delphi code in this report, that may help: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17603

Comment: The idea is clear. I have 2 problems with this code. First "ObjectiveC class PHPhotoLibrary could not be found" Second what it given me AVAssetForVideo but no avplayer is available .